# Convergence of a modified series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a sequence s.t. $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k=0$. 
Is it true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{k}{n})a_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$ (note the RHS may diverge, in which case we interpret "=" to mean the LHS diverges). If this is not true, can we impose a stronger condition to make it true, like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k $ converges, or absolute convergence: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k| < \infty$, or $a_k \downarrow 0$ (decreases monotonically).
I've verified it for the sequences $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and $a_k=\frac{1}{k^2}$. 
My background: I'm wondering if this result can be proven using the same level of math as Rudin's Ch 3 (the chapter on sequences and series), that is I'm comfortable with any result from there.  If more advanced math techniques are required, please let me know.

Comment: Under the assumption of absolute convergence this is true, then you can split the sum on the left into the sum up to $m$ and from $m+1$ to $n$. Holding $m$ fixed and letting $n \to \infty$, the first part will converge to the partial sum $S_m$ of the RHS, and by absolute convergence the rest can be made as small as you wish. I am not sure about the general case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n$ be the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^na_n$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\Bigl(1-\frac{k}{n}\Bigr)\,a_k=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_k-\frac{s_n}{n}.
$$
If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\{s_n\}$ converges and the equality holds. Since $a_n\to0$, $s_n/n$ is bounded, and the equality also holds if $\sum a_k=\pm\infty$.

Comment: Note that absolute convergence is not required.This leave the case where $\sum a_n$ does not converge and does not sum to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Thx for the answer.  By the way, does your argument rely on the fact that if a sequence convergences, then so does the sequence of averages, and to the same limit (Rudin Ch 3 Exercise 14a)?  It seems you need it twice: to say {$s_k$} converges implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$ converges to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$, and $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k=0$ implies $\lim_{n \to infty} \frac{s_n}{n}=0$.

Comment: This nice derivation shows that the converse is not true. You just have to find a sequence $(a_k)$ for which $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges, but the averaged partial sums converge. A simple example is $a_k = (-1)^k$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer But $a_k\not\to0$.

Comment: @Jason Yes, the proof uses that fact.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: True, I missed that, but then there are still counterexamples, just a little harder to write down. E.g., look at the sequence $1,-1,0,0,\ldots,0,1/2,1/2,-1/2,-1/2,0,0,\ldots,0,1/3,1/3,1/3,-1/3,-1/3,-1/3,0,0,\ldots$ where the blocks of zeros are long enough to have the averaged partial sums converge to zero, whereas the partial sums itself do not converge but accumulate on the whole interval $[0,1]$.